# Probably version compatibility errors suddenly started to popup in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, compatibility

I have a code, which was running on Python 2.x

Suddenly it stopped working with strange errors.

First it stopped understanding print without parenthesis:

```
File "MyFile1.py", line 26, in <module>
    import mymodule2
  File "mymodule2.py", line 60
    print f.read()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then it started to be strict with file type writing:

```
with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
    fp.write('jar=./%s\n' % detector_jar_name)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How to flip it back?

Comment: What do you get if you do `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Wow, it is 3.x! Thanks! Somehow Anaconda environment changed python version